# C++ win32 BITMAP object from raw pixel data

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am new to GDI, in my program, I am converting a BITMAP to an array of pixel data, and streaming it. But I can't seem to find any information on how to reconstruct a Bitmap object from the pixel data, there is info on how to do this in C#, and how to save a pixel array as a bmp, but I can't find any examples on how to make a BITMAP object from raw pixel data.

Any help appreciated

Comment: If the purpose of streaming is to show a video, a BMP is a very bad choice.

Comment: I only need about 1fps and I have only a few days to get this done, with no libraries allowed (as the file has to be one exe with no external dependancies)

Comment: Just create a [`BITMAP` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmap) and fill in the fields? Or call [CreateBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap) , which does the same.

Comment: I tried doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
    {
     buf[c + 0] = (BYTE)255;
     buf[c + 1] = (BYTE)0;
     buf[c + 2] = (BYTE)0;

     c += 3;
    }
   }

   BITMAP b;
   b.bmType = 0;
   b.bmBitsPixel = 24;
   b.bmHeight = 128;
   b.bmWidth = 128;
   b.bmWidthBytes = ((b.bmWidth*b.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4;
   b.bmPlanes = 1;
   b.bmBits = buf;

```

But it crashes with no exception given when I try draw it to a GUI

Comment: You can use [CreateDIBSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection) and if you have a stream (_IStream_) you just call _IStream::Read_ to fill _ppvBits_